# How do I keep the filters in a new column?

Tags: powerbi

I have a table 'trabajador' and a table 'capacitacion_trabajador' (1:n) and I want to know how many capacitaciones my 'trabajador' has, so I use CALCULATE ( COUNTROW ( capacitacion_trabajador) ), but also know if it was taken in a period of time, so I have a slicer. When I change the slicer the new measure changes with no problem, but the new column doesn´t, and I need the new column to make graphics, any ideas?

[New column and New measure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nx2BX.png)

Comment: Please could you post the table as text, and the code that you are running that has the problem?

Comment: Columns are calculated once, when the data is loaded, and are not affected by filters. You must use a measure.